# changing font size in longtable changes paragraph spacing

Tags: spacing, longtable, fontsize

For my paper I used longtable, before this longtable I have a small paragraph with text. After changing font size of my longtable the text in the paragraph changes in spacing. Does anyone have a workaround for this?

I use the following code:

```
\chapter{R-values/offset values table}
Table \ref{Rvalues_all} shows the R-values and offset values of all tests which are performed successfully. The values are left blank in  tests were some data was irrelevant, for instance tractor acceleration y in acceleration and braking test. Furthermore, there are some abbreviations used, \textit{ax} denoted acceleration x, with \textit{r} yaw velocity is indicated, \textit{ay} denotes acceleration y and \textit{$\theta$} is used for articulation angle.
\begin{footnotesize}
\begin{longtable}{|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
\multirow{3}{*}{\textbf{No.}} & \multicolumn{7}{l|}{\textbf{Rvalues}}                                                           & \multicolumn{7}{l|}{\textbf{Offset values {[}\%{]}}}                                            \\ \cline{2-15} 
                              & \multicolumn{3}{l|}{\textbf{Tractor}}  & \multicolumn{3}{l|}{\textbf{Semitrailer}} & \textbf{}  & \multicolumn{3}{l|}{\textbf{Tractor}}  & \multicolumn{3}{l|}{\textbf{Semitrailer}} & \textbf{}  \\ \cline{2-15} 
                              & \textbf{ax} & \textbf{r} & \textbf{ay} & \textbf{ax}  & \textbf{r}  & \textbf{ay}  & \textbf{$\theta$} & \textbf{ax} & \textbf{r} & \textbf{ay} & \textbf{ax}  & \textbf{r}  & \textbf{ay}  & \textbf{$\theta$} \\ \hline
01                             & 0.95        & -          & -           & 0.94         & -           & -            & -          & 2.44        & -          & -           & 0.25         & -           & -            & -          \\ \hline
02                             & 0.97        & -          & -           & 0.96         & -           & -            & -          & 1.11        & -          & -           & 0.02         & -           & -            & -          \\ \hline
03                             & 0.95        & -          & -           & 0.94         & -           & -            & -          & 1.28        & -          & -           & 0.10         & -           & -            & -          \\ \hline
04                             & 0.95        & -          & -           & 0.94         & -           & -            & -          & 1.16        & -          & -           & -0.83        & -           & -            & -          \\ \hline
05                             & 0.97        & -          & -           & 0.96         & -           & -            & -          & 0.50        & -          & -           & -1.03        & -           & -            & -          \\ \hline
06                             & 0.99        & -          & -           & 0.98         & -           & -            & -          & 0.56        & -          & -           & 0.01         & -           & -            & -          \\ \hline
07                             & 0.98        & -          & -           & 0.98         & -           & -            & -          & 0.32        & -          & -           & 0.11         & -           & -            & -          \\ \hline
08                             & 0.91        & -          & -           & 0.91         & -           & -            & -          & 0.62        & -          & -           & 0.16         & -           & -            & -          \\ \hline
09                             & 0.59        & 0.91       & 0.41        & 0.61         & 0.94        & 0.27         & 0.93       & 1.31        & -0.50      & -11.2       & 1.01         & 1.64        & -6.32        & 2.53       \\ \hline
10                            & 0.73        & 0.96       & 0.76        & 0.71         & 0.86        & 0.21         & 0.89       & 1.05        & -1.89      & -18.7       & 0.72         & 0.12        & -6.94        & 2.67       \\ \hline
11                            & 0.65        & 0.98       & 0.84        & 0.62         & 0.95        & 0.43         & 0.97       & 1.76        & -0.95      & -13.9       & 1.12         & -0.79       & -6.17        & 1.88       \\ \hline
12                            & 0.62        & 0.98       & 0.82        & 0.62         & 0.98        & 0.40         & 0.99       & 1.36        & -0.73      & -15.1       & 1.19         & 1.67        & -15.8        & 2.14       \\ \hline
13                            & 0.61        & 0.98       & 0.94        & 0.58         & 0.98        & 0.83         & 0.73       & 0.75        & 7.83       & -2.37       & -3.85        & 8.34        & 4.44         & 6.70       \\ \hline
14                            & 0.55        & 0.97       & 0.96        & 0.59         & 0.98        & 0.92         & 0.97       & 0.23        & 7.91       & 3.11        & -4.83        & 8.43        & 5.80         & 6.57       \\ \hline
15                            & 0.59        & 0.99       & 0.86        & 0.50         & 0.99        & 0.77         & 1.00       & 2.94        & 5.32       & 0.41        & 4.50         & 7.84        & 2.01         & -1.20      \\ \hline
17                            & 0.67        & 0.98       & 0.98        & 0.64         & 0.99        & 0.91         & 0.88       & 1.22        & 4.06       & 3.66        & 7.33         & 5.23        & 4.29         & -8.75      \\ \hline
18                            & 0.95        & -          & -           & -            & -           & -            & -          & 1.22        & -          & -           & -            & -           & -            & -          \\ \hline
19                            & 0.97        & -          & -           & -            & -           & -            & -          & 0.46        & -          & -           & -            & -           & -            & -          \\ \hline
20                            & 0.97        & -          & -           & -            & -           & -            & -          & 0.60        & -          & -           & -            & -           & -            & -          \\ \hline
21                            & 0.99        & -          & -           & -            & -           & -            & -          & 0.34        & -          & -           & -            & -           & -            & -          \\ \hline
22                            & 0.99        & -          & -           & -            & -           & -            & -          & 0.64        & -          & -           & -            & -           & -            & -          \\ \hline
23                            & 0.99        & -          & -           & -            & -           & -            & -          & 0.10        & -          & -           & -            & -           & -            & -          \\ \hline
24                            & 0.99        & -          & -           & -            & -           & -            & -          & 0.59        & -          & -           & -            & -           & -            & -          \\ \hline
25                            & 0.99        & -          & -           & -            & -           & -            & -          & 0.10        & -          & -           & -            & -           & -            & -          \\ \hline
26                            & 0.99        & -          & -           & -            & -           & -            & -          & 0.35        & -          & -           & -            & -           & -            & -          \\ \hline
28                            & 0.76        & 0.99       & 0.82        & -            & -           & -            & -          & 0.47        & 6.64       & -1.22       & -            & -           & -            & -          \\ \hline
30                            & 0.80        & 0.99       & 0.99        & -            & -           & -            & -          & -0.49       & 7.97       & 9.97        & -            & -           & -            & -          \\ \hline
31                            & 0.88        & 0.99       & 0.97        & -            & -           & -            & -          & 1.64        & 5.23       & -3.38       & -            & -           & -            & -          \\ \hline
32                            & 0.92        & 1.00       & 0.99        & -            & -           & -            & -          & 0.65        & 4.79       & -0.18       & -            & -           & -            & -          \\ \hline
33                            & 0.97        & 1.00       & 0.88        & -            & -           & -            & -          & 0.89        & -0.83      & -16.9       & -            & -           & -            & -          \\ \hline
34                            & 0.94        & 0.99       & 0.89        & -            & -           & -            & -          & 1.67        & -2.62      & -15.4       & -            & -           & -            & -          \\ \hline
35                            & 0.57        & 1.00       & 0.92        & -            & -           & -            & -          & 1.40        & -2.82      & -12.9       & -            & -           & -            & -          \\ \hline
36                            & 0.95        & 1.00       & 0.95        & -            & -           & -            & -          & 0.47        & -0.70      & -13.0       & -            & -           & -            & -          \\ \hline
37                            & 0.98        & 1.00       & 0.98        & -            & -           & -            & -          & 0.39        & -1.13      & -9.59       & -            & -           & -            & -          \\ \hline
38                            & 0.99        & 1.00       & 0.98        & -            & -           & -            & -          & 0.70        & -0.35      & -9.37       & -            & -           & -            & -          \\ \hline
39                            & 0.93        & 1.00       & 0.98        & -            & -           & -            & -          & 0.64        & -0.74      & -2.89       & -            & -           & -            & -          \\ \hline
40                            & 0.98        & 1.00       & 0.99        & -            & -           & -            & -          & 0.29        & -0.75      & -4.23       & -            & -           & -            & -          \\ \hline
41                            & 0.90        & 1.00       & 0.97        & -            & -           & -            & -          & 0.48        & 0.83       & -9.68       & -            & -           & -            & -          \\ \hline
42                            & 0.95        & 1.00       & 0.99        & -            & -           & -            & -          & 0.54        & 1.14       & -4.27       & -            & -           & -            & -          \\ \hline
43                            & 0.91        & 1.00       & 0.96        & -            & -           & -            & -          & 1.83        & -4.63      & -13.6       & -            & -           & -            & -          \\ \hline
44                            & 0.90        & 1.00       & 0.93        & -            & -           & -            & -          & 0.58        & -2.60      & -8.68       & -            & -           & -            & -          \\ \hline
45                            & 0.94        & 1.00       & 0.98        & -            & -           & -            & -          & 2.00        & -4.73      & -9.07       & -            & -           & -            & -          \\ \hline
46                            & 0.95        & 1.00       & 0.98        & -            & -           & -            & -          & 1.70        & -4.29      & -7.23       & -            & -           & -            & -          \\ \hline
\caption{R-values and offset values of all tests performed}
\label{Rvalues_all}
\end{longtable}
\end{footnotesize}
```

Comment: Please note for the future, that this is not a MWE (minimal working example). A MWE should start at `\documentclass{}` and end at `\end{document}` including all packages necessary to compile your example.

Comment: This is completely unrelated to longtable, if you remove the table from your example you will see the same effect

Comment: Skillmon: Sorry about that, I will change it in the future, I have used multiple packages. 
David Carlisle: Did not notice that removing the table would already change the spacing. I will look on stackexchange ones more to see if more people had this spacing issue whilst using the footnote size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fontsizes are changing the spacing of a whole paragraph. To prevent LaTeX from changing the spacing of the above paragraph you should properly seperate the table and the paragraph with a `\par` or an empty line:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}
\chapter{R-values/offset values table}
Table \ref{Rvalues_all} shows the R-values and offset values of all tests which are performed successfully. The values are left blank in  tests were some data was irrelevant, for instance tractor acceleration y in acceleration and braking test. Furthermore, there are some abbreviations used, \textit{ax} denoted acceleration x, with \textit{r} yaw velocity is indicated, \textit{ay} denotes acceleration y and \textit{$\theta$} is used for articulation angle.

\begin{footnotesize}
\begin{longtable}{|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
\multirow{3}{*}{\textbf{No.}} & \multicolumn{7}{l|}{\textbf{Rvalues}}                                                           & \multicolumn{7}{l|}{\textbf{Offset values {[}\%{]}}}                                            \\ \cline{2-15} 
                              & \multicolumn{3}{l|}{\textbf{Tractor}}  & \multicolumn{3}{l|}{\textbf{Semitrailer}} & \textbf{}  & \multicolumn{3}{l|}{\textbf{Tractor}}  & \multicolumn{3}{l|}{\textbf{Semitrailer}} & \textbf{}  \\ \cline{2-15} 
                              & \textbf{ax} & \textbf{r} & \textbf{ay} & \textbf{ax}  & \textbf{r}  & \textbf{ay}  & \textbf{$\theta$} & \textbf{ax} & \textbf{r} & \textbf{ay} & \textbf{ax}  & \textbf{r}  & \textbf{ay}  & \textbf{$\theta$} \\ \hline
01                             & 0.95        & -          & -           & 0.94         & -           & -            & -          & 2.44        & -          & -           & 0.25         & -           & -            & -          \\ \hline
02                             & 0.97        & -          & -           & 0.96         & -           & -            & -          & 1.11        & -          & -           & 0.02         & -           & -            & -          \\ \hline
03                             & 0.95        & -          & -           & 0.94         & -           & -            & -          & 1.28        & -          & -           & 0.10         & -           & -            & -          \\ \hline
04                             & 0.95        & -          & -           & 0.94         & -           & -            & -          & 1.16        & -          & -           & -0.83        & -           & -            & -          \\ \hline
05                             & 0.97        & -          & -           & 0.96         & -           & -            & -          & 0.50        & -          & -           & -1.03        & -           & -            & -          \\ \hline
06                             & 0.99        & -          & -           & 0.98         & -           & -            & -          & 0.56        & -          & -           & 0.01         & -           & -            & -          \\ \hline
07                             & 0.98        & -          & -           & 0.98         & -           & -            & -          & 0.32        & -          & -           & 0.11         & -           & -            & -          \\ \hline
08                             & 0.91        & -          & -           & 0.91         & -           & -            & -          & 0.62        & -          & -           & 0.16         & -           & -            & -          \\ \hline
09                             & 0.59        & 0.91       & 0.41        & 0.61         & 0.94        & 0.27         & 0.93       & 1.31        & -0.50      & -11.2       & 1.01         & 1.64        & -6.32        & 2.53       \\ \hline
10                            & 0.73        & 0.96       & 0.76        & 0.71         & 0.86        & 0.21         & 0.89       & 1.05        & -1.89      & -18.7       & 0.72         & 0.12        & -6.94        & 2.67       \\ \hline
11                            & 0.65        & 0.98       & 0.84        & 0.62         & 0.95        & 0.43         & 0.97       & 1.76        & -0.95      & -13.9       & 1.12         & -0.79       & -6.17        & 1.88       \\ \hline
12                            & 0.62        & 0.98       & 0.82        & 0.62         & 0.98        & 0.40         & 0.99       & 1.36        & -0.73      & -15.1       & 1.19         & 1.67        & -15.8        & 2.14       \\ \hline
13                            & 0.61        & 0.98       & 0.94        & 0.58         & 0.98        & 0.83         & 0.73       & 0.75        & 7.83       & -2.37       & -3.85        & 8.34        & 4.44         & 6.70       \\ \hline
14                            & 0.55        & 0.97       & 0.96        & 0.59         & 0.98        & 0.92         & 0.97       & 0.23        & 7.91       & 3.11        & -4.83        & 8.43        & 5.80         & 6.57       \\ \hline
15                            & 0.59        & 0.99       & 0.86        & 0.50         & 0.99        & 0.77         & 1.00       & 2.94        & 5.32       & 0.41        & 4.50         & 7.84        & 2.01         & -1.20      \\ \hline
17                            & 0.67        & 0.98       & 0.98        & 0.64         & 0.99        & 0.91         & 0.88       & 1.22        & 4.06       & 3.66        & 7.33         & 5.23        & 4.29         & -8.75      \\ \hline
18                            & 0.95        & -          & -           & -            & -           & -            & -          & 1.22        & -          & -           & -            & -           & -            & -          \\ \hline
19                            & 0.97        & -          & -           & -            & -           & -            & -          & 0.46        & -          & -           & -            & -           & -            & -          \\ \hline
20                            & 0.97        & -          & -           & -            & -           & -            & -          & 0.60        & -          & -           & -            & -           & -            & -          \\ \hline
21                            & 0.99        & -          & -           & -            & -           & -            & -          & 0.34        & -          & -           & -            & -           & -            & -          \\ \hline
22                            & 0.99        & -          & -           & -            & -           & -            & -          & 0.64        & -          & -           & -            & -           & -            & -          \\ \hline
23                            & 0.99        & -          & -           & -            & -           & -            & -          & 0.10        & -          & -           & -            & -           & -            & -          \\ \hline
24                            & 0.99        & -          & -           & -            & -           & -            & -          & 0.59        & -          & -           & -            & -           & -            & -          \\ \hline
25                            & 0.99        & -          & -           & -            & -           & -            & -          & 0.10        & -          & -           & -            & -           & -            & -          \\ \hline
26                            & 0.99        & -          & -           & -            & -           & -            & -          & 0.35        & -          & -           & -            & -           & -            & -          \\ \hline
28                            & 0.76        & 0.99       & 0.82        & -            & -           & -            & -          & 0.47        & 6.64       & -1.22       & -            & -           & -            & -          \\ \hline
30                            & 0.80        & 0.99       & 0.99        & -            & -           & -            & -          & -0.49       & 7.97       & 9.97        & -            & -           & -            & -          \\ \hline
31                            & 0.88        & 0.99       & 0.97        & -            & -           & -            & -          & 1.64        & 5.23       & -3.38       & -            & -           & -            & -          \\ \hline
32                            & 0.92        & 1.00       & 0.99        & -            & -           & -            & -          & 0.65        & 4.79       & -0.18       & -            & -           & -            & -          \\ \hline
33                            & 0.97        & 1.00       & 0.88        & -            & -           & -            & -          & 0.89        & -0.83      & -16.9       & -            & -           & -            & -          \\ \hline
34                            & 0.94        & 0.99       & 0.89        & -            & -           & -            & -          & 1.67        & -2.62      & -15.4       & -            & -           & -            & -          \\ \hline
35                            & 0.57        & 1.00       & 0.92        & -            & -           & -            & -          & 1.40        & -2.82      & -12.9       & -            & -           & -            & -          \\ \hline
36                            & 0.95        & 1.00       & 0.95        & -            & -           & -            & -          & 0.47        & -0.70      & -13.0       & -            & -           & -            & -          \\ \hline
37                            & 0.98        & 1.00       & 0.98        & -            & -           & -            & -          & 0.39        & -1.13      & -9.59       & -            & -           & -            & -          \\ \hline
38                            & 0.99        & 1.00       & 0.98        & -            & -           & -            & -          & 0.70        & -0.35      & -9.37       & -            & -           & -            & -          \\ \hline
39                            & 0.93        & 1.00       & 0.98        & -            & -           & -            & -          & 0.64        & -0.74      & -2.89       & -            & -           & -            & -          \\ \hline
40                            & 0.98        & 1.00       & 0.99        & -            & -           & -            & -          & 0.29        & -0.75      & -4.23       & -            & -           & -            & -          \\ \hline
41                            & 0.90        & 1.00       & 0.97        & -            & -           & -            & -          & 0.48        & 0.83       & -9.68       & -            & -           & -            & -          \\ \hline
42                            & 0.95        & 1.00       & 0.99        & -            & -           & -            & -          & 0.54        & 1.14       & -4.27       & -            & -           & -            & -          \\ \hline
43                            & 0.91        & 1.00       & 0.96        & -            & -           & -            & -          & 1.83        & -4.63      & -13.6       & -            & -           & -            & -          \\ \hline
44                            & 0.90        & 1.00       & 0.93        & -            & -           & -            & -          & 0.58        & -2.60      & -8.68       & -            & -           & -            & -          \\ \hline
45                            & 0.94        & 1.00       & 0.98        & -            & -           & -            & -          & 2.00        & -4.73      & -9.07       & -            & -           & -            & -          \\ \hline
46                            & 0.95        & 1.00       & 0.98        & -            & -           & -            & -          & 1.70        & -4.29      & -7.23       & -            & -           & -            & -          \\ \hline
\caption{R-values and offset values of all tests performed}
\label{Rvalues_all}
\end{longtable}
\end{footnotesize}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @T.vandeWiel you should note that putting one or more empty lines in the code is the same as using `\par`. And just to make it more clear: You have to start a new paragraph before using fontsize switches to get the spacing right.